# copy files on EC2 slowing down very fast

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm running a simple test when i'm copying 6 GB of files from one directory to other.
I'm doing this test on R4.4xlarge instance of AWS.
The disk is 300 GIB and the IOPs are configured to 600 on the specific volume.

What i'm facing is very wierd, in the begining it start copying in rate of more than 600 MB/sec and after few seconds it slowing down dramatically to 20 MB /sec.

The volume type (file system type) is IO1, and the OS is windows

Any idea of what could cause this behaviour?

Comment: from where are you uploading the file?

Comment: I'm copying from one folder to the other on the same instance

Comment: What type of file system? What is the block size for the file system? SSD or HDD volumes? EBS optimized EC2 instance? Add this information to your question. This article might help http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ebs-io-characteristics.html

Comment: One thing silly but maybe worth pointing out is, depending on how you measure the speed, these running measurements are usually not accurate in the beginning.

Comment: EBS will provisioned 3 iops per GB of disk space. So 300GB x 3  = 900iops. 
Please clarify the what you mean "the IOPs are configured to 600 on the specific volume". Unless you purposely use io1 than gp2, and this is strange.  According to AWS , `*io1/gp2 based on 16K I/O size`  . You can do the calculation to get the approximate transfer rates

Comment: @jingx is correct.  Writes are buffered by the kernel until some threshold is reached, unless you are  making `fsync()` system calls on your open filehandles, which don't return until the data is actually committed to disk.  This gives an illusion of very fast throughput at the beginning.

Comment: @mootmoot When i said IOPS configured to 600 i meant that this is the  maximum requested number of IO the volume can support.

Comment: @John Hanley The volume type (file system type) is IO1.

Comment: as mentioned, you are restricted by the 16kbps/iops . You can do the calculation.  There is many way to increase the speed,  e.g. use gp2 and allocate more GB; use multiple volume; get a SSD based instance volume.

Comment: @mootmoot i'm sorry but i'm not sure i have understand.... can you please ellaborate more.
I'm using multiple volumes and now i'm adding format step to the process in order to warm up each new volume i'm adding.
The volume is type io1, and it's ssd, at least based on: [this comparrison](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSVolumeTypes.html) ... am i missing here something, please advise

Comment: AWS storage is a tedious topics. In short, your io1  speed is bound to the IOPS limit.   i.e. IOPS x 16Kbps  . 20MB/sec is somewhat the correct upper limit for your setup.   IMHO, if this is not used for database, I will rather use the gp2 setup, assign 600GB disk space,  I will get 600 x 3 = 1800 IOPS, ironically , this is faster and cheaper than your io1 setup.

Answer (score 1):

AWS storage topics is a beast.  In short, i suggest you go through the following material.

Slide share : [Deep Dive: Maximizing EC2 and EBS Performance](https://www.slideshare.net/AmazonWebServices/deep-dive-maximizing-ec2-and-ebs-performance)

Youtube :  [Deep Dive: Maximizing EC2 and EBS Performance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gUYa7RzrNhM)